# What is the license for the Java Imaging API?

Tags: java, jai

What is the license for the Java Imaging API?

I'm using one of their classes in a project and I have been trying googling around for a specific license without any success.

Comment: Well, it's on the wiki site. Didn't require much googling...

Comment: As you see in your answer's comments it is debated. But as usual you get 5 downvotes at SO as soon as you ask something that people think is "simple".

Comment: I'm sorry SO is not nice to you today ;) I don't think it is so much "debated" as rather nobody cares for or about JAI anymore, so it is basically just "floating" around on the net without anything official behind it. Whatever information you find, it is likely to be outdated. But since the JNI-free jars have been put in Maven, you can be sure it is free for distribution. The other license may be part of the JAI versions which have native code attached to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Advanced Imaging's [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Advanced_Imaging) page states that the license is [**Java Research License**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Research_License).

Direct link to the license is in the official sources [here](http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/LICENSE-jai.txt) (version 1.1.3)

Comment: their maven artifact says java distribution license - http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/media/jai_core/1.1.3/jai_core-1.1.3.pom

Comment: @radai That's interesting. So which name is the official one? I added the link to the license in the official source package.

Comment: i suppose distribution is under 1 license and contribution/usage under another? this is basically why all of their "community" attempts keep failing :-)